# 403 forbidden when running custom docker container in vs code jupyter notebook

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I am following a course on udemy for docker with python. I am supposed to be creating a custom docker image by pulling down the pre-existing `jupyter/tensorflow-notebook` image which does not have pytorch installed in it, install pytorch and torchvision then run it in a jupyter notebook.

I get a 403 forbidden error when I run it and I can't figure out why. Here are the steps in order:

1. docker pull jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
2. docker run -d --name temp jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
3. docker exec -it temp pip install torch torchvision
4. docker stop temp
5. docker commit temp myjupyter:torch
6. docker run -it -rm -p 8888:8888 -v ${PWD}:/home/joyvan/notebooks myjupyter:torch (my working directory is the folder containing the ipynb file that the course will have me working in once the image is running successfully)

I've seen some other SO posts that say to check `docker container ps` and that returns

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
(base) justinbenfit@MacBook-Pro-3 manual-build %
```

so I'm assuming temp images don't show up so I'm not really sure what to do next to find out why the server is saying forbidden. Thanks.

Comment: `docker ps -a` will show all *containers*, not images. Check `docker images` for your `myjupyter` image

Comment: Thanks! Ok I see myjupyter but I don’t really know how to use the information it shows me to understand why that would cause the Jupyter server to return a 403 error.

Comment: When does the 403 occur? Are you able to post any logs?